# Pull-To-Request covers other views

Tags: android

I am using this library to implement a pull to request for listView:
[Link to project](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView)

The result looks quite nice but I am facing a problem.
If I drag the listview down to reload it, the arrow occurs and all is working fine. 
But it covers the whole other views. So during the reload my other views disapear and show up after the refreshing is finished. This looks quite ugly. Does someone give me a hint how to avoid this.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/help"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sorting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/newest_title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/balken"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3sp"
    android:background="@color/main_color" >
</TextView>



<eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_listview"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to fix it.
I simply added a LinearLayout around the Listview.